# How many ways can the integers 1,2,3,4,5,6 be arranged so that the 2 is adjacent to either 1 or 3?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can the integers 1,2,3,4,5,6 be arranged so that 2 is adjacent to either 1 or 3?

(And this includes the fact that 2 can be next to both 1 and 3.)

---

I tried to draw a hexagonal graph. Then I did the following:

- I counted all paths that include the pair 2,3. So, 234561, 234516, 234165, etc. I got 12 such paths.
- Since I can start at any number in chain, I get 12*6=72 paths.
- And since the paths can be reversed (e.g. 234561 can be written backwards as 165423), I get  12*6*2=144 paths.
- I repeated this process for all paths now that include 2,1. I get another 144 paths.

So I thought my answer was 144+144=288 paths.

But the correct answer is **432**. I think there are more paths than the ones I considered. What am I missing?

Comment: A question about the wording:  Is there a single $2$?  If so, your question should read "How many ways can the integers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ be arranged so that $2$ is adjacent to either $1$ or $3$.''

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes, I dont know why I wrote "either" twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *inclusion/exclusion* principle:

- Include the number of arrangements containing "12", which is $5!=120$
- Include the number of arrangements containing "23", which is $5!=120$
- Exclude the number of arrangements containing "123", which is $4!=24$
- Include the number of arrangements containing "32", which is $5!=120$
- Include the number of arrangements containing "21", which is $5!=120$
- Exclude the number of arrangements containing "321", which is $4!=24$

Hence so total number of such arrangements is $120+120-24+120+120-24=432$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your graph idea works at all.

Here is one way to do it:

- Count how many arrangements have "12" as a substring. (Hint: it's $5!$.)
- Do the same for "21", and "23", and "32".
- Now you have double counted arrangements containing "123" and "321", so count how many such arrangements there are and subtract (inclusion-exclusion).